# Is using @Entity annotation in Spring boot JPA creates a table?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, oracle10g

**BACKGROUND**

I am new to developing API in spring boot. I have this project wherein it is connected to an Oracle DB and PostgreSQL. The Oracle DB already have an existing tables and I need to fetch some data from multiple tables and send it back as a response. The Postgres DB is where I store the users data and other some data that doesn't need to be stored in the Oracle DB. I am currently using `native queries`.

The `Account` is an entity wherein I just marked one of the columns as the `@Id` (It is actually not an Id but it is unique for all accounts):

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Account {
  @Id
  private String sampleProperty1;
  private String sampleProperty2;
  private String sampleProperty3;
  private String sampleProperty4;
  private String sampleProperty5;
}
```

Now I have a repository interface:

```
public interface IAccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, String> {
  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM TABLE(SAMPLE_PACKAGE.SAMPLE_FUNC_GETACCOUNTS(?1))", nativeQuery = true)
  List<Account> getAllAccountsByClientNumber(String clientNumber);
}
```

I was able to fetch the data and JPA mapped the columns automatically to my entity. Basically I am creating an Entity (Spring boot) for the data in my Oracle DB where the only purpose of it is to map the data and send it back to the user.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Will this approach create a table in my Oracle DB? I checked the Oracle DB and there is no table. But I'm worried it might somehow create a table of `ACCOUNT` in the oracle DB when it is on production. If this might happen, how can I prevent it?
2. This scenario also applies to other functionality like fetching transaction history, creating transaction, updating the Account data that are all in the Oracle DB. Am I doing it just right or there is a better option?
3. Is creating an Entity without a corresponding table have a drawback in Spring boot?

**Note**

I know you might say that I should just use the Oracle DB and create entities based on the existing tables. But in the future of the API, it will not have a connection with the Oracle DB. I already tried using projections it was also good, but I still needed to create a Response model and mapped it then send it back to user and creating a unit tests using the projection is pretty long and it sucks haha

Comment: @Entity annotation identifies a class as an entity class. Use spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true to generate the tables automatically.

Answer (score -2):

You can set the following property:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

**update** will update your database if database tables are already created and will create if database tables are not created.

Comment: Sorry but your reply is not what I am looking for. Please read the whole question.